# Как выровнять текст и иконку по центру?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как выровнять текст и иконку по центру,чтобы они были на одном уровне ? На данный момент текст находится у нижней части иконки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.responsive__offer-icon{
 display: inline-block;
}

.responsive__offer-text{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.fa-check-circle{
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 color: #87aaa8;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive__offer">
                <div class="responsive__offer-icon">
                  <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="responsive__offer-text">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>

               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если брать Ваш фрагмент кода, можно для `fa-check-circle`задать `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
.responsive__offer-icon{
 display: inline-block;
}

.responsive__offer-text{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.fa-check-circle{
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    color: #87aaa8;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive__offer">
    <div class="responsive__offer-icon">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="responsive__offer-text">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>

</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c7ecb22548.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

vertical-align: middle; для иконки.

- +можно выровнять через

```css
.responsive__offer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: ваш пример не показывает изменений

Comment: ты о чем?)))  я написал  решение проблемы к тому же не одно а два.

Comment: тыкни "выполнить код" в своем примере и примере выше

Comment: @ZaArs смешно, он и не должен ничего показывать. исправил на precode.

Comment: так то лучше) вернул +1